# estoy ejecutando un formulario de Windows C# datos de sql y me da un error "la cadena de entrada no tiene el formato correcto "

Tags: c#, sql

```
  #el error#
```

*parece que no ejecuta los obj y salta al catch
presenta el mensaje de la cadena de entrada no tiene el formato correcto*

```
   private void btnIgreso_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var obj = new Compra();
                String mensaje;
                obj.idcomprador = int.Parse(cboNc.SelectedValue.ToString());
                obj.nomvendedor = txtNv.Text;
                obj.fecha = dtpFec.Value;
                obj.ecacao = cboEsC.Text;
                obj.tcaco = cboTpS.Text;
                obj.cancacao = float.Parse(txtcan.SelectedText.ToString());
                obj.tipo = rbtExpor.Checked;
```

#continuidad#
*esta es la continuidad del codigo para ser cincero estoy aprendiendo el lenguaje y no lo domino muy bien*

```
            if (Program.idcom == 0)//nuevo
            {
                mensaje = obj.grabar();
                if (mensaje == null)
                { MessageBox.Show("Compra realizada"); }
                else
                { MessageBox.Show(mensaje); }
            }
            else//modificar
            {
                obj.idcompra = Program.idcom;
                mensaje = obj.modificar();
                if (mensaje == null)
                { MessageBox.Show("Compra modificado"); }
                else
                { MessageBox.Show(mensaje); }
            }
            forma.mostrarDatos("");
            btnEliminar_Click(sender, e);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Si salto al catch, entonces tuviste un error.. si tuviste un error, aparecio toda una explicacion del error.. la proxima vez, pone el error completo...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Las propiedades del objeto Compra (idcomprador, nomvendedor, etc) seguramente su tipo de dato no corresponde al valor que le estas asignando en el boton ingreso (poner un int en un string por ejemplo)

Comment: Gracias, amigo, estuve investigo y note que habia declaro mal esta linea obj.cancacao = float.Parse(txtcan.SelectedText.ToString());  pero la forma correcta era obj.cancacao = float.Parse(txtcan.Text);

Comment: Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]